# How is $\mathsf{Set}^{C^\mathsf{op}} \cong (\mathsf{Set}^C)^\mathsf{op}$?

Tags: category-theory

This is subtly referenced in Riehl's Category Theory in context; namely, a corollary of the Yoneda lemma for locally small categories is that the evaluation bifunctor is naturally isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(y-, -)$.

In showing this, the isomorphism in the title is implicitly used, and I've had no luck in proving this. Are there any pointers/tips for showing this is the case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is quite false so I doubt Riehl uses it. It is already false for $C = 1$.

Comment: It's indeed completely false. Are you thinking of $\mathrm{Set}^{C^{op}}\simeq (Set^{op})^C$?

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted the statement it seems. From what I gather, it's more about the relationship between functors $C \to D^\mathsf{op}$ and $C^\mathsf{op} \to D$, applied to the Yoneda embedding $y: C^\mathsf{op} \to \mathsf{Set}^C$. I'm guessing this is wildly different from my initial question; I'll edit my question as soon as possible to reflect this.

Comment: @CaptainLama: that is also wildly false and in particular already false for $C = 1$! I think you need another op in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.
To see this, consider for $C$ the one-object, one-morphism category, so that $D^C ≅ D$ for every category $D$.
On the one hand we have
$$
  ( \mathsf{Set}^C )^{\mathrm{op}} ≅ \mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}} \,.
$$
On the other hand we have $C^{\mathrm{op}} ≅ C$ and thus
$$
  \mathsf{Set}^{(C^{\mathrm{op}})}
  ≅
  \mathsf{Set}^C
  ≅
  \mathsf{Set} \,.
$$
But the categories $\mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ are not equivalent.
(In $\mathsf{Set}$ there exists a morphism from the initial object to the terminal object, but not the other way around.
In $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ the situation is reversed.)

What is true, however, is that
$$
  (D^C)^{\mathrm{op}} ≅ (D^{\mathrm{op}})^{(C^{\mathrm{op}})}
  \tag{$\ast$}
$$
for any two categories $C$ and $D$.
This is due to the following two observations:

- A functor from $C$ to $D$ is the same as a functor from $C^{\mathrm{op}}$ to $D^{\mathrm{op}}$.
  Hence $(D^C)^{\mathrm{op}}$ and $(D^{\mathrm{op}})^{(C^{\mathrm{op}})}$ have the same objects.
- Let $F, G \colon C \to D$ be two functors and let $α \colon F \Rightarrow G$ a natural transformation.
  This means that the components $α_X \colon F(X) \to G(X)$ are morphisms in $D$ such that the square
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      F(X)         @> α_X >>   G(X)       \\
      @V F(f) VV               @VV G(f) V \\
      F(Y)         @> α_Y >>   G(Y)
    \end{CD}
  $$
  commutes for every morphism $f \colon X \to Y$ in $C$.
  This is a commutative diagram in $D$.

  If we regard $F$ and $G$ as functors $F', G' \colon C^{\mathrm{op}} \to D^{\mathrm{op}}$, then we can express the above square equivalently as the diagram
  $$
    \require{AMScd}
    \begin{CD}
      F'(X)        @< α_X <<   G'(X)       \\
      @A F'(f) AA              @AA G'(f) A \\
      F'(Y)        @< α_Y <<   G'(Y)
    \end{CD}
  $$
  in $D^{\mathrm{op}}$.
  Therefore, $α$ becomes a natural transformation from $G'$ to $F'$.
  This leads to the occurrence of $(-)^{\mathrm{op}}$ in the left-hand side of $(\ast)$.